# Oscillator failure

Tags: microcontroller, oscillator

I faced to a really strange issue on our boards. We have some boards with some same crystals and micros. I could program all the micros through serial connector without any error and I got the final OK indicating that the programming has been done, but when I started to test the micros to see if they are programmed well or not I saw that some of them are not working.

I checked all the voltage supplies, all were OK.

I checked the crystal on the not working boards and I saw that it's not oscillating. I changed the crystal to cross out if it's not working but nothing changed.

I can see the voltage on the oscillator 2V5 which is what I expected but no oscillation.

The micro is a Renesas RX66T - [Datasheet](https://www.renesas.com/eu/en/document/dst/rx66t-group-datasheet-rev121)
The crystal is a CTS 407F35E012M5000 - [Datasheet](https://www.mouser.es/datasheet/2/96/ctsc_s_a0011291532_1-2265037.pdf)

You can see the circuit partially below:

[image]
[image]

I appreciate any kind of suggestion.

Comment: Have you tried replacing the crystal on one of the non-working boards and see if it resolves the issue? Seems like the obvious step 1 to figure out cause or effect

Comment: @Mukira, Yes, it was the first thing that I've done. It didn't work.

Comment: As your question doesn't contain something that you then revealed to @Mukira you'd tried, please edit your question and explain everything you've already tried so everything can start from the where you actually are now.  (Don't post it in comments otherwise people have to piece together the situation. Better answers are likely to come from a better, clearer question.) Thanks.

Comment: As this issue is clock related, seeing a layout of the PCB or even a photo would have been useful

Comment: @Mukira OK. I'm gonna add a screen shot of the layout.

Comment: Mukira may have a point which needs to be checked, however generally MCU IO pins and PCB wiring could account in the order of 5 to 10 pF additional stray capacitance, so 20 pF caps are not much off. Of course the MCU documentation may indicate suitable capacitor range, and 20pF could be near the high end already, so it is possible that the crystal is just unsuitable to be reliably used with the MCU. Has the gm been calculated and has it enough margin from the critical gm required for startup?

Comment: @Justme I think 5 to 10 pF of stray capacitance is borderline negligent on anyone laying the PCB out. Example: a 10 mm by 2 mm parallel plate capacitor having a separation of 0.3 mm would only produce 2 pF in FR4 material. [Calculator #1](https://www.omnicalculator.com/physics/capacitance).

Comment: @Andyaka The Renesas data sheet says IO pin capacitance is max 8 pF. Of course it would not always be 8 pF but much less.

Comment: This chip has *oscillator stoppage detection*. I wonder if this facility is used during initialization (and what is done when "stoppage" is detected? Sometimes, timing is involved in this detection - a slow-starting xtal may give a false-detect. Perhaps your "working" oscillators are marginal - a slow oscillation amplitude build-up on power-up is worrisome. 12.5MHz frequency might also be on the high-side. Looks like xtal's pin 2,4 float (pkg case) - these might best be GND from an EMI perspective.

Comment: The CL that you have now as per my understanding is atleast 22pF||22pF + 5pF = 16pF. Requirement is 20pF. Lower load cap causes a frequency error for sure. However, is this causing oscillations to not startup? If changing c1, c2 doesn't help a) Can you check whether you are able to program the bad board using the serial port again and clear your code and see if oscillations start? Reason is if it were xtal issue, how did it work the first time? Could it be code related issue b) Is bad board drawing more current c) We can feed external clock on EXTAL & reset & see if the board starts working

Comment: For future reference, a common nasty problem is crystal errors happening because someone dropped the crystal tape & reel or mounted PCB. You can get intermittent, mysterious errors from that - somewhat similar to ESD damage, since you might never learn how exactly the part broke.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I got the answer of why the oscillator wasn't oscillating. That was so dummy. There was a soldering bridge backside of the board. The PCB manufactuerer has soldered this bridge in some of the boards.
I wanted to share this with you.

[image]

Thank you so much for all your support.

Comment: You should "accept" your own answer here --> [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) (even though it was an obscure problem) that I couldn't predict.

Answer (score 3):

The obvious mistake is that you haven't fitted the right loading capacitance. Read this about the [specific model](https://www.mouser.es/datasheet/2/96/ctsc_s_a0011291532_1-2265037.pdf) you used (CTS 407F35**E**012M5000) ⇒ note the highlighted "E": -

[image]

So, when it says you need a load capacitance of 20 pF, it means 40 pF in series with 40 pF to make 20 pF. Your circuit uses two 22 pF capacitors: -

[image]

Comment: Sorry for asking a question on your answer, but in cases like this, how critical is accounting for the stray capacitance? Do you just assume a nominal 3-5pF

Comment: I have the same load capacitors 22pF on working boards. I'm not sure how critical would be this, but I'm gonna change it to see if it affects.

Comment: XTLIN capacitance will be dominated by the chip (maybe 3 pf). Maybe 0.5 pF from tracks.

Comment: @Andyaka I changed the capacitors to 20pF, the result is the same as before. it doesn't oscillate.

Comment: You need to change the capacitor to 40 pF. 40 pF in series with 40 pF = 20 pF. I guess 33 pF to 39 pF will do. This is what I said in my answer: *So, when it says you need a load capacitance of 20 pF, it means 40 pF in series with 40 pF to make 20 pF.*

Comment: You might also need to add 100 ohms to 1000 ohms in series with the oscillator out pin to permit a more likely chance of oscillator starting cleanly and, simultaneously reducing the power into the crystal (gut feeling tells me that you might be exceeding the max power of the crystal on a 5 volt supply). Because of this latter point, it's possible that some crystals have become damaged.

Comment: @Andyaka you are totally right. I changed the capacitors to 39pF each, but it doesn't work either. I'm gonna add the resistor en series.

Comment: If thaqt doesn't work then I suspect the crystals may have become damaged.

Comment: @Farzaneh if we are done here, please take note of this: [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.